# IONIC on IE9 not working

Tags: angularjs, internet-explorer-9, ionic-framework

I've someone please could provide some workaround for this one?
If I run my IONIC application in IE9, i'm getting the error back:

> Unable to get value of the property 'indexOf': object is null or
>   undefined ionic.bundle.min.js, line 6, character 31181.

When viewing the JS file. The exact line is:

```
var o=t.CSS.TRANSITION.indexOf('webkit');
```

Did somebody encountered this problem? Or has a fix for it?

I know that IONIC is meant for hybrid mobile dev, but I really need to get this working on IE9 also.

Answer (score 0):

If you want it to be viewable in a browser for testing, then Chrome or Safari work just fine.

Support for IE desktop is not on the road map. Ionic's mission is hybrid apps.

http://ionicframework.com/docs/guide/preface.html119

Comment: Like I said. I know that the mission of IONIC is hybrid apps for mobile platforms. I've figured out that IE9 lacks the support for CSS3 transitions. That's why some sort of map or list returns an undefined. So this is unsolvable.

Comment: it works in WebKit browsers so ... IE9 it's not supported, sorry pal